# How to use Node.js script as TTY using Upstart

Tags: node.js, upstart

I've got a Node.js command line interface that I'd like to use by default when booting up this Linux system, which is using Upstart (RHEL).

Right now I'm trying to replace the default TTY, mingetty, with my own script, I just haven't had any luck.

I've added my own .conf script to /etc/init that runs the script, but when I override the tty.conf and the serial.conf, I get an empty shell, it never displays my script's output.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The utility `openvt` is used for exactly this.  For example, copy `/etc/init/start-ttys.conf` into a `/etc/init/start-ttys.override` as Upstart likes you to do when editing its init files, and replace the line that calls `mingetty` with a line that asks `openvt` to run your utility.